Getting Nested List Boxes on a User Form to read from a Data Table in VBA
I am very new to VBA. I am a cabinet making shop and have created a Job Tracking spreadsheet which has Userforms and a Data Table of jobs with all sorts of info to do with these jobs. I got most of my inspiration and code from watching You Tube video’s and reading forums. I have got to a point
I have created a User Form that my colleagues use to track jobs in our cabinet making shop by doing a search for a job or entering a new job.
I have a dropdown for the Builder, then a dropdown for the Supervisors, that  the builder has, and the phone numbers for those Supervisors. The problem is, I have the Builders, Supervisors and Phone Numbers in my VBA code because I can’t figure out how to get VBA to refer to a table in another worksheet.
I tried to put the Builders name, Supervisor and Phone numbers in a Table and get VBA to read it but I can't figure out how to tell VBA to go and look at this table and bring back the results.
Here is the way I have it at the moment. It works fine but my colleagues should be able to update a table if we get a new builder and not edit the VBA code...
'Set up Builder Dropdown list
'These are the Builders we use

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ComboBox2.List = Array("BIDI Builders", "Shelford Building", "LKS Building Services", "Unita Builders")
    
 End Sub


'These are the Builders' supervisors

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    ComboBox3.Clear

    cmbboxselect = ComboBox2.Value
    Select Case cmbboxselect
            Case "BIDI Builders"
            ComboBox3.List = Array("Marco", "Craig")
            Case "Shelford Building"
            ComboBox3.List = Array("Trevor", "Danny")
            Case "LKS Building Services"
            ComboBox3.List = Array("Paul", "Aaron")
            Case "Unita Builders"
            ComboBox3.List = Array("Luke", "Josh")
    End Select
    
End Sub


'These are the Builders' supervisors Phone Numbers

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    ComboBox4.Clear
cmbboxselect = ComboBox3.Value
    Select Case cmbboxselect
            Case "Marco"
            ComboBox4.AddItem "0413 111 111"
            Case "Craigo"
            ComboBox4.AddItem "0413 222 222"
            Case "Trevor"
            ComboBox4.AddItem "0413 333 333"
            Case "Danny"
            ComboBox4.AddItem "0413 444 444"
            Case "Paul"
            ComboBox4.AddItem "0413 555 555"
            Case "Aaron"
            ComboBox4.AddItem "0413 666 666"
            Case "Marco"
            ComboBox4.AddItem "0413 777 777"
            Case "Luke"
            ComboBox4.AddItem "0413 888 888"
            Case "Josh"
            ComboBox4.AddItem "0413 999 999"
    End Select
    
End Sub


The first step for you is to populate your dropdowns with data from a spreadsheet.
Place the Builder, Supervisor, and Phone Numbers in a table format on a worksheet. Let's assume this table is on a sheet named "Data" and has columns like "Builder", "Supervisor", and "Phone".  You can read those values to your form in the following way:
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim builderTable As ListObject
    Dim builderCell As ListRow
    Dim builderName As String
    Dim supervisorName As String
    Dim phoneNumber As String
    
        ' Set the worksheet and table
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        Set builderTable = ws.ListObjects("BuilderTable") ' Replace "BuilderTable" with your actual table name
    
        ' Clear previous items just in case
        Me.cboBuilder.Clear
        Me.cboSupervisor.Clear
        Me.cboPhoneNumber.Clear
    
        ' Populate the Builder names
        For Each builderCell In builderTable.ListRows
            builderName = builderCell.Range(1, 1).Value ' Assuming the first column is Builder names
            If Not IsEmpty(builderName) Then
                Me.cboBuilder.AddItem builderName
            End If
        Next builderCell
        ' continue like that with other list boxes '
End Sub


I'd add that to get the table you can highlight your data and press Ctrl+T, once it's created a Table Design ribbon will appear when a cell is selected within the table.  You can rename the table from within that ribbon.
